# ¿Por qué me sale error cuando me logueo?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy validando un inicio de sesión que al ponerle los datos me aparece error que son datos incorrectos ya me ayudaron a conectar la tabla e inserté bien los datos, pero el *login* me dió error

conexion.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        include ("configuracion.php");
        $conexion = new mysqli ($server,$user,$pass,$bd);

        if (!$conexion) {

            $msg="Conexión imposible. Revise las credenciales de conexión";    
        } else {

            $usuario=!empty($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : NULL;
            $password=!empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : NULL;
            $repassword=!empty($_POST['repassword']) ? $_POST['repassword'] : NULL;


            $nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
            $correo=!empty($_POST['correo']) ? $_POST['correo'] : NULL;

            if($usuario && $password && $repassword && $nombre) { 
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';

                $rec = $conexion->query($sql); 

                $verificar_usuario = FALSE;

                 while($result = $rec->fetch_object()) { 
                    if($result->usuario == $usuario) { 
                        $verificar_usuario = TRUE; 

                            break; 
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día

Tienes un problema con tus variables que están en tu consulta, no están definidas o inicializadas, por tal motivo te muestra el error

Conexion.php

```
    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        include ("configuracion.php");
        $conexion = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $bd);

        if (!$conexion) {
            $msg = "Conexión imposible. Revise las credenciales de conexión";
        } else {
            $usuario = !empty($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : NULL;
            $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : NULL;
            $repassword = !empty($_POST['repassword']) ? $_POST['repassword'] : NULL;


            $nombre = !empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
            $correo = !empty($_POST['correo']) ? $_POST['correo'] : NULL;

            if ($usuario && $password && $repassword && $nombre) {
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';

                $rec = $conexion->query($sql);

                $verificar_usuario = FALSE;

                while ($result = $rec->fetch_object()) {
                    if ($result->usuario == $usuario) {
                        $verificar_usuario = TRUE;

                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!$verificar_usuario) {
                    if ($password == $repassword) {
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,correo,usuario,password) VALUES ('$nombre','$correo','$usuario','$password')";
                        if ($conexion->query($sql) && $conexion->affected_rows > 0) {
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Usted se ha registrado correctamente."); window.location.href="index.php"; </script>';
                        } else {
                            $msg = "Error en la inserción";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $msg = "Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente.";
                    }
                } else {
                    $msg = "Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente.";
                }
            } else {
                $msg = "Por favor llene todos los campos. Faltan datos en el POST";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $msg = "No hay POST enviar";
    }
    echo $msg;
    ?>
```

Verificar.php

```
include ("conexion.php");
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $query = $conexion->query(" SELECT idusuarios FROM usuarios WHERE password='$password' and usuario='$usuario'");

    while ($result = $query->fetch_object()) {
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $_SESSION['password'] = $row['usuario'];
            header('location:admin.php');
        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Datos incorrectos!</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ES QUE AL HACER include conexion

las variables las declare hay
 $usuario=!empty($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : NULL;
            $password=!empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : NULL;

Comment: las tengo en include conexion las variables

Comment: Podrías hacer un`var_dump($_POST);` dentro de tu `if (isset($_POST['login'])) {`

Comment: ya me salio

T enviararray(3) { ["usuario"]=> string(8) "rmendoza" ["password"]=> string(3) "123" ["login"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Igualmente dentro de tu `if (isset($_POST['login'])) {` puedes hacer un `echo` de tus variables por favor.

`echo $password;`, `echo $usuario;`

Comment: ahora me salio esto ya que tambien declare las variables
enviararray(3) { ["usuario"]=> string(8) "rmendoza" ["password"]=> string(3) "123" ["login"]=> string(0) "" } 123rmendoza
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\deportes\LoginPHP\index.php on line 11

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\deportes\LoginPHP\index.php on line 12
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\deportes\LoginPHP\index.php on line 13

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que tienes en tu archivo conexion.php por favor.

Comment: ya lo hice mira 
aqui el complemento 

if(!$verificar_usuario) { 
    
    if($password == $repassword) { 
     
     $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre,correo,usuario,password) VALUES
        ('$nombre','$correo','$usuario','$password')";

Comment: if ($conexion->query($sql) && $conexion->affected_rows > 0) {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
      alert("Usted se ha registrado correctamente.");
      window.location.href="index.php";
      </script>';
      
      
      
     } else {
      $msg="Error en la inserción";
     }
    } else { 
     $msg="Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente."; 
    } 
    } else {
    
    $msg="Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente."; 
    }

Comment: } else {
    $msg="Por favor llene todos los campos. Faltan datos en el POST";
    }
    }
    
    } else {
    $msg="No hay POST enviar";  
    }
    
    echo $msg;

Comment: Puedes revisar lo que edite de mi pregunta principal, por favor.

Tienes un detalle con el **mysqli_query**

Comment: esta 
mysqli_query($link, $query);

La función mysqli_query, funciona a través de 2 parámetros

Donde el primero es la variable de tu conexión con tu base de datos

Mientras que el segundo es tu query (consulta)

Comment: Esta incorrecto como tienes tu código

Podrías poner en tu pregunta, ambos códigos, tanto donde realizas tu conexión y donde haces tu validación. (Ahora que lo editaste, eliminaste tu código pasado)

Así podría indicarte bien donde estan los errores

Comment: te lo puedo mostrar por correo??
rober.josue.mendoza

arroba hotmail.com

Comment: Modifique mi respuesta y viene junto tus 2 códigos, puedes probarlo, por favor.

Comment: conexion y verificar.php verdad

Comment: lo agrege y me salior 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\deportes\LoginPHP\verificar.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\deportes\LoginPHP\index.php(3): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\deportes\LoginPHP\verificar.php on line 5